# Yii2 : Flot charts extension labelFormatter usage

Tags: php, yii2, format, pie-chart, flot

I'm trying to utilise the Yii2 Flot extension with more or less success. However, I'm having trouble altering the labels of a pie-chart using a labelFormatter function.

This is the extension I'm using: [bburim/flot](https://github.com/bburim/flot)

Here is the code I have so far, it generates a nice chart, but I cannot alter the labels.
Any help is appreciated.

```
echo Chart::widget(
    [
        'data' => [
            ['label' => 'Series1', 'data' => [1, 12]],
            ['label' => 'Series2', 'data' => [1, 16]],
            ['label' => 'Series3', 'data' => [1, 89]],
            ['label' => 'Series4', 'data' => [1, 44]],
            ['label' => 'Series5', 'data' => [1, 38]],
        ],
        'options' => [
            'series' => [
                'pie' => [
                    'show' => true,
                    'label' => [
                        'show' => true,
                        'treshold' => 0.1,
                        'radius' => 0.6,
                        'value' => 'value',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'grid' => [
                'hoverable' => true,
            ],
            'legend' => [
                'position' => 'nw',
                'show' => true,
                'font' => [
                    'size' => 16,
                ],
                'margin' => 10,
                'backgroundOpacity' => 0.5,
            ],
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            Plugin::PIE,
        ],
        'htmlOptions' => [
            'class' => 'chartdiv',
        ],
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a pretty broad term to say customize, I will assume it means providing custom label text, its pretty simple and straight forward you just need to use the [`new JsExpression()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-jsexpression) for the callback function to work correctly

```
echo Chart::widget(
    [
        'data' => [
            ['label' => 'Series1', 'data' => [1, 12]],
            ['label' => 'Series2', 'data' => [1, 16]],
            ['label' => 'Series3', 'data' => [1, 89]],
            ['label' => 'Series4', 'data' => [1, 44]],
            ['label' => 'Series5', 'data' => [1, 38]],
        ],
        'options' => [
            'series' => [
                'pie' => [
                    'show' => true,
                    'label' => [
                        'show' => true,
                        'treshold' => 0.1,
                        'radius' => 0.6,
                        'value' => 'value',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'grid' => [
                'hoverable' => true,
            ],
            'legend' => [
                'labelFormatter' => new JsExpression("function(label, series) {
                    // series is the series object for the label
                    return '<a href=\"#' + label + '\">Custom Label for '+series.label+'</a>';
                }"),
                'position' => 'nw',
                'show' => true,
                'font' => [
                    'size' => 16,
                ],
                'margin' => 10,
                'backgroundOpacity' => 0.5,
            ],
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            Plugin::PIE,
        ],
        'htmlOptions' => [
            'class' => 'chartdiv',
        ],
    ]
);
```

*On a side note I wont use that repo as the owner seems to be unresponsive since 2015 not a single reply on the issues, you might have to maintain or fix the bugs your self so better fork the repo and use your own customized version*

Comment: Thanks, although I had to customise it a bit, this worked nicely! - Also thanks for the heads-up about the extension.